# Aligning range column data with x axis labels in chart control

Tags: c#, charts, alignment, series

I'm trying to do a range column plot of a set of agents' tasks using the Chart control in C# .NET. I plot agent number across the x axis and task time along the y axis. My only problem is that the column data will not align properly with the agent numbers on the x axis. Does anyone know how to align the columns with their corresponding x axis labels?

Here is an image of my graph:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    chartSchedule.Titles.Add("Agent / Task Schedule");
    chartSchedule.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Agent";
    chartSchedule.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Time";

    int index = 0;
    foreach ( Agent a in _agents )
    {
        // Create a series for each agent and set up display details
        Series agentSeries = chartSchedule.Series.Add("Agent " + a.Id);
        agentSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn;

        // Alternate colours of series lines
        if ( index % 2 > 0 )
          agentSeries.Color = Color.DodgerBlue;
        else
          agentSeries.Color = Color.Blue;

        // Display start and end columns of every task
        List<DataPoint> timeData = new List<DataPoint>();
        foreach ( NodeTask t in a.AssignedTasks )
        {
            agentSeries.Points.AddXY(index + 1, t.StartTime, t.EndTime);
        }

        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the post to include a link to my graph image

Comment: This is great! I tried it out and it does exactly what I want. I just had to change the Legends[0].CustomItems line which is a property of chartSchedule not agentSeries. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the seeming 'misalignment' is that you are adding a total of five series but each has only one (set of) Datapoint(s) per X-Value.

**This existent DataPoint is then combined wih the the four non-existent DataPoints and the five of them are displayed side by side as one block centered at the X-Values/Labels.** This looks only right for the middle Series, which actually has the middle point.

You could add a few the other Points to see the effect..:

```
    agentSeries.Points.AddXY(1, 1, 4);
    agentSeries.Points.AddXY(2, 1, 2);
    agentSeries.Points.AddXY(4, 1, 3);
```

[image]

So the most natural solution is to not add Series with missing data.

Not sure if you are happy with this solution or if there is a better way to do it, but the result looks not so bad..

[image]

I have done away with adding all those series and instead **add all data to one and same Series**.

To create the Legends I hide the regular one by setting its color to transparent. (It needs to be there.) Then I add new Legend `CustomItems` and give them the colors and names as you did.

Here is the code I used, except for the actual data, which I have simulated:

```
    chartSchedule.Series.Clear();
    ChartArea CA = chartSchedule.ChartAreas[0];

    chartSchedule.Titles.Add("Agent / Task Schedule");
    chartSchedule.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Agent";
    chartSchedule.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Time";

    // our only Series
    Series agentSeries = chartSchedule.Series.Add(" " );
    agentSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn;
    agentSeries.Color = Color.Transparent;  // hide the default series entry!

    agentSeries["PixelPointWidth"] = "20"; // <- your choice of width!

    int index = 0;
    foreach (Agent a in _agents)
    {
        // Alternate colours 
        Color color = index % 2 == 0 ? Color.DodgerBlue : Color.Blue;

        // Display start and end columns of every task
        List<DataPoint> timeData = new List<DataPoint>();  ///???
        foreach (NodeTask t in a.AssignedTasks)
        {
            int p = agentSeries.Points.AddXY(index +1, t.StartTime, t.EndTime);
            agentSeries.Points[p].Color = color;
        }

        chartSchedule.Legends[0].CustomItems.Add(color, "Agent " + index);
        index++;
    }
```